# how to rescue specific exceptions in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am executing a sql function and capturing standard error. is it the right way? if not how can i catch specific exception?

```
    query = ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize(sql)
    begin
      result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(query)

    rescue StandardError => e
      raise Programmability::FatalError.new(nil, e.inspect)
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

You're catching a semi-specific exception. To catch a specific exception change `StandardError` to the error you're interested in.

You have all the information you need in `e`, so if you want to know more, `Rails.logger.debug(e.class)` will add information to `log/development.log` so you can tune your `rescue`.

Comment: Thanks tadman. can you tell me what would be the specific exception i can change with StandardError? also is there any way i can also show the query in error?

Comment: You can use `Rails.logger` to log all sorts of information, including the `query` variable. I don't know what exception you're trying to capture, but I've explained how you can find out.